# Dual display with MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) and would like to set up two 24" Acer monitors so I can have an easier working life. The monitors support CDMI, DVI and VGA, I am new to MacBooks, so I'm not sure where to go or what to do, anything you can advise will be wonderful.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mac technically can only support it's own internal display and one external display.  However, there is a "hack" that you can use to get a 3rd screen (2nd external monitor)

What you will need:

- [mini Display Port to DVI cable/adapter](http://radnex.us/hdmi_20_cable_4k)
- [USB to DVI adapter](http://radnex.us/startech-usb-dvi-adapter)

There's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8gE-ckBwjE) with someone using this method with 3 external monitors (total of 4 screens) so this is entirely doable.  Keep in mind that the bandwidth on USB is nowhere near the bandwidth of DisplayPort so there will be some lag when it comes to intensive video type applications.  In other words, don't expect excellent results if you are gaming.

Comment: will that have two independent displays or just one big screen?

Comment: They can be either independent or mirrored.  Mirrored is self explanatory.  Independent can be arranged so it becomes one big display.

Answer (score 0):

Some MacBook Pros **only allow 1 external monitor**. **The way to get around it** is with adapters (see the article ["How to connect two or more external displays to an M1 or M2 MacBook"](https://www.macworld.com/article/675869/how-to-connect-two-or-more-external-displays-to-apple-silicon-m1-macs.html)) and drivers. Many places on the internet suggested using USB adapter hubs with DisplayLink as a driver. Unfortunately, **DisplayLink didn't work for me**, but when I used the same adapter hub with [InstantView](https://plugable.com/pages/siliconmotion), it worked straight out of the box.

Personally, I used the EZQuest USB-C Hub 12-in-1 USB-C Docking Station, one of my monitors is plugged into the VGA input, and the other into the HDMI input.